# filter data set when both conditions are met

Tags: r, dplyr

I have some data that requires that the first day of every year be removed (1/1/xx), but I want to leave all of the other days of January. It doesn't follow traditional date formats, but has a Month and day columns. I've tried subsetting several ways using "&" in an effort to make sure it only removes the row when both requirements are met, but it isn't working and it removes all days from January. Here's a reproducible example of what I have been trying.

```
Month <- sample(1:12, 1000, replace=TRUE)
Day <- sample(1:30, 1000, replace = TRUE)
X <- sample(1:100, 1000, replace = TRUE)
df.ex <- as.data.frame(cbind(Month, Day, X))

library(dplyr)
df.ex <- df.ex %>% 
  filter(Month != 1 & Day != 1)
```

This results in all January dates being removed and all of the 1st days of the months being removed.

Answer (score 0):

Here, you need to use the `!` operator to negate your whole condition:

```
df.ex %>% 
  filter(!(Month == 1 & Day == 1))
```